# apktool not recognized as external or internal command

Tags: java, android, windows

I'm trying to run android APKtool on my windows 7 machine, but getting the error shown in the title. I've downloaded `APKtool-install-windows-r05-ibot`, `APKtool1.5.2 package` and the `apktool.jar` files have been present inside the folder `apktool.jar`. I have also have checked both `JDK` and `JRE` has been installed and Environment variables are also set for both of them. I also tried `$ ./apktool.jar` and `framework-res.apk` but I'm still getting the same error. Just for info, I have also added the below path to the env variables,

`C:\Program Files\Android\sdk\platform-tools Tools - C:\Program Files\Android\sdk\tools,C:\Program Files\Android\sdk\build-tools\18.1.0.`

Please let me know how to fix this error or anything that I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder name :ApkToolPath.

The ApkToolPath folder is located at C:/  and it contains aapt.exe,apktool.bat and apktool.jar

In cmd run this command
c:>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java" -jar ApkToolPath\apktool.jar

After that cd ApkToolPath

cd:\ApkToolPath>apktool d name_of_apk.apk

Answer (score 3):

C:\ cd < apktool.jar directory here > ENTER

C:\ java -jar apktool.jar

If you don't have the Path of java set,

C:\ "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java" -jar < apktool.jar directory here>\apktool.jar

Answer (score 0):

After extracting  apktool-install-windows-r05-ibot and apktool1.5.2 package

try to put the content which were inside both folders into same folder say xml. Then run the command

Answer (score 0):

The problem I have been facing was due to .JAR format was not included in the "PATHEXT" variable. In Advanced system settings, click on Environment Variables, in that window look for PATHEXT in system variables column and add .JAR in the end of that variable.

Answer (score -1):

in start find Edit Environment Variables
and click in variable user new 
1 variable name -> PATH 
2 variable user -> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin

Comment: This is very nearly jibberish. Try re-writing your answer.